# How Java and C manage memory of local variable?

Tags: java, c, memory

I'm considering about how Java and C manage variable in a scope.

In java, every iterator, I create a new object and then print it. The result say that each iterator I have a new Object.

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        while (true) {
            Ideone object = new Ideone();
            System.out.println(object);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And variable of scope in C. I do the same as I do in Java. Every iterator I create a variable and print its address. But the result make me confusing because it's returning the *same address*, because I think every iterator it create a new variable at a *random address*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while (1) {
        int variable;
        printf("%p\n", &variable);
    }
}
```

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's under the hood of Java and C ?? And why C do not create a random address for it's variable ?

**EDIT 1:**

I have another question about dynamic memory management in C like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    while (1) {
        int *variable = malloc(sizeof(int));
        printf("%p\n", variable);
    }
}
```

[image]

In this case, they print different address after each iterator. And each address is more then the previous the constant size.

But if free the memory like this, now it print the same address

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    while (1) {
        int *variable = malloc(sizeof(int));
        printf("%p\n", variable);
        realloc(variable, 0);
    }
}
```

[image]

Is C memory management do not generate random address for new variable ?

Comment: why would you expect 2 different languages to handle different type of variables the same way? What happened when you used `int` in java instead of object? You're eating apples and oranges and expecting them to taste the same

Comment: Optimization, maybe?

Comment: It's just what happens to happen. The behaviors could be flipped and both would still be reasonable and consistent with the way the language is specified.

Comment: Try to assign some value to your C variable: int variable=10:

Comment: May be Java is really random, whereas C just finds a random new place to store a variable when the previous one is fulled ? That way since `0x7fff7331559c`is still free at each iteration, C does not bother looking for a new random adress ? Intesting question

Comment: C and JAVA are hardly comparable concerning the way they handle about anything.

Comment: There's one major difference between your two snippets: in the Java snippet you create a new object on the heap and even though the reference variable `object` gets removed when the scope is left (new iteration) the object on the heap still exists and thus new objects need to be stored in a different address. In the C snippet the variable itself is being removed (and thus the memory is freed) when you leave the scope.

Comment: One final thing: what you see in the Java output is _not_ the address. It's the objects' hashcode in hex (the default implementation of `toString()` is `return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`) and even though the default hash code is probably based on the memory address it is _not_ the address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, the `new Ideone()` objects lifetime is not bound to a scope, you could return it from a function.

In your C code, `int variable;` creates an object that is automatically destroyed when you reach the end of the scope it was defined in.

Many implementations of C use a stack to allocate such objects. A stack will always give you the same address when used this way.

This comparision is a bit like apple vs. oranges. Comparing Java's `new` to C's `malloc` would show a similar behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing apples to kumquats here - you're printing out the *value* of `object` (which is the address of something explicitly created on the heap each time through the loop) vs. the *address* of `variable` (which is an `auto` object that's *typically* allocated from the runtime stack).

`variable` has `auto` storage duration, meaning that storage for it is only guaranteed to be allocated over the lifetime of its enclosing scope (i.e., the body of the loop).  However, as a matter of practice, most C compilers will allocate space for all `auto` variables in a function at function entry, even if the scope of those variables is limited to a smaller block within the function.  IOW, the space for `variable` is allocated once, so its address doesn't change from iteration to iteration.  And, given how most C implementations manage `auto` objects, it would be allocated from the same address *anyway* if it were allocated and deallocated with each loop iteration.

A more direct comparison would be looking at the *address* of the `object` variable itself, not its value, but I'm not sure how you would obtain that information (been a *long* time since I've done any Java).

Answer (score 1):

In your Java code, you explicitly create a new object with every run in the loop. Thus, it is very likely that the different objects yield different memory addresses.

In you C-code, in contrast, you do not "create" anything, because variables are actually not "created". They are concepts of the programming language, and the compiler may decide when, where, and how often it reserves memory for the variable to hold a value. In practice, local variables are placed on the stack once at the beginning of a function or a loop, so it seems as if it were "created" only once, but this is actually something you cannot rely on.

Note, however, that the situation becomes a different one if you allocate "objects" in C as well. This would be rather comparable then to what Java does (in Java, all class-based types are handled through a pointer, but this isn't exposed to the user):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    while (1) {
        int *variable = malloc(sizeof(int));
        printf("%p\n", variable);
    }
}
```

Besides memory leaks and running out of memory, this will print different memory addresses with each iteration.

Comment: You can have a memory leak in java by holding a reference to an object so it can't be garbage collected!!!!!

Comment: @LucasHolt, if you can reach a given object via a reference, then by definition, that object's memory has not leaked.  You can retain an object longer than you need it that way, but that's not the same thing as a memory leak.

Comment: @Lucas Holt: Actually it was not my intention to state anything about Java's garbage collector behaviour. It's just been to clarify that the C code clearly leaks.

Comment: Strictly true, but in practice it has the same exact net result.  Consider a weak hash map scenario.

Comment: I have edited my question.... Can you tell me why my "EDIT 1" is happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Java use virtuel machine JVM. The garbage collection delete the variables when it's not needed any more.
In C the variables are stored in the stack or heap which you need you use `malloc` to allocate memory and `free` to deallocate.

Your output shows the address of variable in hexadecimal where in memory it's located and it's compilers decision in which memory address it should be stored.

`local variables` are put on the stack since in your code you did not used `malloc` to allocate memory on the `heap`it will give you the same address because `stack` is **Last-in-first-out** and your loop PUSH and POP in the same address, but if you close your terminal and run it again it will give you different address.

[image: test one]

Close terminal and reopen run again it gives different address.

[image: testtwo]